# Movie with people creating the hologram of a fake mummy

Tags: story-identification, movie

The movie was in English (not sure whether it was dubbed or not). I saw a part of this movie when I was a kid (it's really difficult to remember when I saw it but I am 100% sure that I saw it before 2008) and after some time the power went off so I couldn't see the movie name. The power came back much later and by that time the movie was finished and I kept on wondering what it was.

So the scene which I saw was like the following (I am recreating this from a memory older than two decades so there can be some error but I am pretty sure that I remember it correctly):

I think all the scenes were in black and white (not sure). First scene I saw was there is a boy studying on a study table and in front of his face has a window which gives the view of a valley kind of thing. Now when the boy is reading his book **one woman swings on a rope from one side of the valley to the other side making some sound** but when the boy looks up she has already reached the other side and there are several people on both the sides to help her. I think this goes on for 1 or 2 swings and then a next scene starts.

In this scene, a husband and a wife are sleeping on bed (but probably awake), I think the same people who were on both sides of the valley bring **a mirror to reflect moon light on a man who is wrapped in white cloth strips (like a mummy) and this creates a hologram of this man inside the couple's bedroom**.

*So think of this like, the moon light that is being reflected in the couple's bedroom is obstructed by this 'mummy man' due to which his hologram inside the couple's bedroom is created.*

And that hologram tries to kill the wife with a knife and the husband tries to save her and then the hologram stabs the husband and the husband cries in pain but then he realises there was no pain ... and then the power went off.

I tried many failed attempts to search it but so far no luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This could be [*"High Spirits"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Spirits_(film)), a 1988 fantasy/comedy movie.

A group of people working in a decrepit bed-and-breakfast set in an old castle has the idea to make money spicing it up and pretending it is haunted by supernatural presences.
They initially try to trick their guests with some cheap tricks (costumes, moving furniture), but their shenaningans awake some *real* ghosts (so there is a fantasy element).

Comment: The whole movie can be easily found on YouTube. There scenes you remember (woman "flying" past a window, projected "ghost") are from about minute 20 to 24.

Comment: Oh my goodness, this is beyond incredible! I never in my wildest dreams imagined I'd have the opportunity to see it once more. Words cannot express the depths of gratitude I feel towards you. You, my friend, have earned my respect, thanks. :)

Now I would be able to die peacefully.

Comment: lfurini, BTW how did you find it!!

Comment: @TheMaskedTitan I watched the movie long ago, and the "mirror hologram" in your description made be remember it (but I had completely forgotten the presence of the real ghosts). I googled for `movie pretend haunted castle mirror ghost` which returned the title, then checked imdb and youtube for clips.